# How to identify what type of costum arraylist contains an Object?

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist

I have a server(Java)/client(Android) aplication, and in the server side, depending on request i send 3 type of objects over ObjectOutputStream.

The Object types are as follows:

In the java server side:

```
//My serializable classA
MySerializableClassA classA = MySerializableClassA(A, B, C);
out.WriteObject(classA);

//Arraylist of my serializable classB
ArrayList<MySerializableClassB> classB = new ArrayList<MySerializableClassB>();
classB.add(new MySerializableClassB(E, F, G, H));
out.writeObject(classB);

//Arraylist of my serializable classC
ArrayList<MySerializableClassC> classC = new ArrayList<MySerializableClassC>();
classC.add(new MySerializableClassC(Y, X, Z));
out.writeObject(classC);
```

And in Android client side:

```
Object obj
private MySerializableClassA classA;
private ArrayList<MySerializableClassB> arrayClassB;
private ArrayList<MySerializableClassC> arrayClassC;

//Here i get the object received, i store it in a Object
in = new ObjectInputStream(_socket.getInputStream());
obj = in.readObject();

//And I check of which class is an instance
if(obj instanceof MySerializableClassA){
    classA = (MySerializableClassA)obj;
    //Do a specific action
}
```

The problem starts here, because a cast from Object to ArrayList is Unchecked,

```
//I check if object is instanceof ArrayList...
else if(obj instanceof ArrayList){
    //and here a need to identify the type of the object inside the arraylist , so... 
    if(the object inside is an instanceof MySerializableClassB){
        arrayClassB = (ArrayList<MySerializableClassB>)obj;
        //Do a specific action
    }
    else if(the object inside is an instanceof MySerializableClassC){ 
        arrayClassC = (ArrayList<MySerializableClassC>)obj;
        //Do a specific action
    }
}
```

So my question is: 
Is there any way to identify what type of costum arraylist contains my object? 
Or to identify what type of object contains my arraylist in this case?

Also I have the option of merging the classB and classC in a single class... but if i can do what I asked above, would be better.

Any help or suggestions of other ways to do what I want is welcome, thanks.

Comment: You could pull the first `Object` out of it using `.get()` and test that, but there's *got* to be a cleaner way to accomplish this.

Comment: why not simply wrap each of the arraylists in a serializable type and identify it using instanceof ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem you're facing is called [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). At runtime, there is no way to discern `List<A>` from `List<B>`. You may work around it by either wrapping your list into an object with method like

```
Class<T> getItemType();
```

or creating two different ArrayList subclasses and then using [`getActualTypeArguments()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments%28%29). That second option would be quite weird.

If your use-case allows it, the simplest would be to iterate through the list and decide for each item. It shouldn't matter that check will yield the same result for each item.

Wrapping the list into an object carrying the item type adds some metadata to the stream. If you want to avoid creating that wrapper, you can either write the type to the stream manually before each list thus defining custom protocol. If you go down that road, consider [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or alike.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what you said is true, there is no way to discern List<A> from List<B>. So i tried to use a single data structure for both (Uniting List<A> and List<B>), but it wasn't an optimal solution, so what I did was continue using List<A>. And besides, send the Class B objetcs one by one, and on the client side, create List<B> as a buffer for these data. Sorry for late reply.